# Why does this python code double the size of my file without changing it?

Tags: python, file, io

Basically I'm just trying to write a string out to a file after editing it and as a proof-of-concept I'm just trying to make what should be a meaningless change. However, as is shown in the below example, even this will for some reason double the size of my output. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
content = StringIO.getvalue()
with open("real.png", 'wb') as dump:
    dump.write(content) #35KB
content = [str(ord(char)) for char in content]
content = "".join([hex(int(char)).lstrip("0x").zfill(2) for char in content])
with open("new.png", "wb") as dump:
    dump.write(content) #70KB
```

Comment: I have also checked that the content of both the real.png file and the new.png file is visually identical. Could the downvote be explained? I would love to make this a better question.

Comment: If the content is identical, it must be the same size .. so how *does* the content differ?

Comment: **visually** identical. Meaning that a text editor shows them as being identical.

Comment: What are you using to verify the contents?

Comment: Is UTF-16 perhaps being used somewhere? Is the correct output file really opened? Since it is claimed to be *visually identical*, these ideas come to mind - a binary file and a hex-encoded representation tend to look quite different when opened. Use a *binary/hex editor* or *binary diff* to see for certain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are converting every byte to a 2-byte string representing the hex value of that byte. A hex string representation is **not the same thing** as the original byte.

I'd be very surprised if that *did not* double the size of the file.

If you are using a HEX editor to look at the original image that *displays* the bytes as hexadecimal characters, then you are confusing one editors representation of that data with the actual contents of the file.

If you wanted to do that task more efficiently, you can use the [`binascii.hexlify()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) to do it in much less code. The mirror operation is called [`binascii.unhexlify()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify):

```
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

content = StringIO.getvalue()
hex_content = hexlify(content)
same_content = unhexlify(hex_content)
assert content == same_content
```

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify as to how exactly I would use binascii.hexlify here? I tried it in place of the second line and that just broke everything.

Comment: Could you please explain how I can do what I am clearly trying to do here? I appreciate the feedback, but this is still a task I need to perform, and yelling at me for misunderstanding what I was doing and then not explaining how to do it correctly is really frustrating :/

Comment: Thanks for the example, but that seems to be exactly the opposite of what I'm actually trying to do. I'd like to have both of these files be the single byte version.

Comment: It is **not clear** what you are trying to do. You say you made a meaningless change; I am pointing out you did not make a meaningless change. What you *are* trying to do you didn't state.

Comment: I'm trying to make a meaningless change. **"I'm just trying to make what should be a meaningless change"**

Comment: **Why** are you trying to make a meaningless change? To what kind of data are you trying to do that?

Comment: What you did was convert all bytes to string representations of those bytes. That change is **not** meaningless.

Comment: It's a png file and I basically need the data to be in different forms to do some processing on it. I need the bytes to be in a string representation for the processing, and then I need some way to undo that change so I can write it back and have it still be readable as a png.

Comment: Your question is like asking how to walk backwards without actually moving, then proceeding to show how you made a double backflip and are wondering why you ended up in a different place.

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere; I inferred from context that this was a PNG image. But your question lacks any and all detail as to what you are trying to do. I've updated my answer to show that `hexlify()` has an inverse operation, turning hex representations back in to bytes.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much, that's what I was looking for. Sorry for the misunderstanding.